# How to set Content-Length to Avoid 411 Error?

Tags: java, url

In Java, due to errors received when POSTing, I am trying to correctly set the Content-Length header, but no matter what I try, I get the "Length Required, 411" error.

```
String theURL  =  "https://<the_url>";
byte[] postDataBytes = (theURL).toString() .getBytes("UTF-8");
URL getToken = new URL(theURL);
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) getToken.openConnection();
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setRequestProperty ("Authorization", "Basic tc1jdfadfakdjfhalsdjh");
conn.setRequestProperty("content-type", "application/json");
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(postDataBytes.length));
conn.connect();
String response = conn.getResponseMessage() + " (" + conn.getResponseCode() + ")";

System.out.println(response);
```

> Prints: "Length Required (411)"

Doing the same Request in POSTMAN works fine so I'm not sure what's off in the code above. I checked other Stack postings, but didn't find what the problem was.

Suggestions to get this working?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you already reviewed answers for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60439440/http-response-411-length-required-when-communicating-with ?

Comment: this post seems to be related to [this link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26247555/http-post-request-in-java-setting-content-length) also
I'll suggest you check this thread out for few workarounds if you don't mind.

Comment: Thanks but I tried all the suggestions there, but am still getting the Length Required error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [content-length in HttpURLConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47594463/content-length-in-httpurlconnection). You are not sending the body for the request. Once you do that the content length should be automatically generated.

Comment: Yes, thank you! That fixed it. I appreciate it. Thanks again.